# Creating dataframe and mapping nested dictionaries to key:value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a little stuck with the following problem:

I want to take the following dictionaries:

```
gasDict ={'Chair': {'CO2': 0.4, 'Methane': 0.5, 'Other': 0.6},'House': {'CO2': 0.4, 'Methane': 0.2, 'Other': 0.3}}
```

```
purchaseDict = {'Bob': ['Chair', 'House'], 'Jim': ['Chair']}
```

And create the following dataframe:

```
| Name | Purchase| CO2   | Methane |Other |
|:---- |:-------:|:-----:|:-------:|-----:|
| Bob  | Chair   | 0.4   |  0.5    | 0.6  |
| Bob  | House   | 0.4   |  0.2    | 0.3  | 
| Jim  | Chair   | 0.4   |  0.5    | 0.6  |
```

My two challenges are 1) Creating a name column with repeating names for the # of corresponding value list items; and 2) mapping the three gasDict nested key:value pairs with the corresponding 'purchase' key from the purchaseDict.

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
gasDict = {
    "Chair": {"CO2": 0.4, "Methane": 0.5, "Other": 0.6},
    "House": {"CO2": 0.4, "Methane": 0.2, "Other": 0.3},
}

purchaseDict = {"Bob": ["Chair", "House"], "Jim": ["Chair"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Name": k, "Purchase": vv, **gasDict[vv]}
    for k, v in purchaseDict.items()
    for vv in v
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Name Purchase  CO2  Methane  Other
0  Bob    Chair  0.4      0.5    0.6
1  Bob    House  0.4      0.2    0.3
2  Jim    Chair  0.4      0.5    0.6
```

Comment: I like the lookup approach in the comprehension.

Comment: Hi Andrej, I haven't used kwargs before (newer than most to python). Can you explain what is happening with that **gasDict[vv] term please?

Comment: @JNams `**gasDict[vv]` is *expanding* values from `gasDict[vv]` into the dictionary. So `{"Name": k, "Purchase": vv, **gasDict[vv]}` becomes `{"Name": k, "Purchase": vv, "CO2": 0.4, "Methane": 0.5, "Other": 0.6}` for example.

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to convert `gasDict` and a list comprehension for `purchaseDict`. Then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) them together:

```
gasDict = {'Chair': {'CO2': 0.4, 'Methane': 0.5, 'Other': 0.6},
           'House': {'CO2': 0.4, 'Methane': 0.2, 'Other': 0.3}}

purchaseDict = {'Bob': ['Chair', 'House'], 'Jim': ['Chair']}

df_gas = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gasDict, orient='index')
df_purchase = pd.DataFrame([(k, v)
                            for k, lst in purchaseDict.items() for v in lst],
                           columns=['Name', 'Purchase'])
df = df_purchase.join(df_gas, on='Purchase')
```

`df`:

```
  Name Purchase  CO2  Methane  Other
0  Bob    Chair  0.4      0.5    0.6
1  Bob    House  0.4      0.2    0.3
2  Jim    Chair  0.4      0.5    0.6
```

Comment: Thank you @Henry Ecker. If there were additional 'purchases' in the gasDict that did not appear in the purchaseDict list items, would this method still work? Would there be NaN rows?

Comment: Yes. There would be NaN rows. `purchaseDict = {'Bob': ['Chair', 'House'], 'Jim': ['Chair'], 'Tim': ['Table']}` would give the last row as `3  Tim    Table  NaN      NaN    NaN`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative based off of @Henry Ecker's answer. Instead of using a comprehension, you can also construct a `DataFrame` and use `.explode`

```py
gasDict = {
    "Chair": {"CO2": 0.4, "Methane": 0.5, "Other": 0.6},
    "House": {"CO2": 0.4, "Methane": 0.2, "Other": 0.3},
}

purchaseDict = {"Bob": ["Chair", "House"], "Jim": ["Chair"]}


df_gas = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gasDict, orient="index")
df_purchase = (
    pd.DataFrame(purchaseDict.items(), columns=["Name", "Purchase"])
    .explode("Purchase")
)

out = df_purchase.join(df_gas, on='Purchase').reset_index()

print(out)
  Name Purchase  CO2  Methane  Other
0  Bob    Chair  0.4      0.5    0.6
1  Bob    House  0.4      0.2    0.3
2  Jim    Chair  0.4      0.5    0.6
```